# ng-repeat array from json file

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, controller, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm very new to AngularJS, and have tried to find an answer to my following question around the web.

So my issue is as follows:
I have a handler (.ashx) file on my site. The handler returns a JSON array. It's located on the following URL: /services/returnsites.ashx

It's a quite simple JSON aray that looks like this:

```
[{"NodeId":a93064,"NodeName":"Planes"},{"NodeId":a49856,"NodeName":"Bicycles"},{"NodeId":a19631,"NodeName":"Cars"}]
```

I'd like to loop through each of the sites in the json array.

I have an html-file containing this:

```
<div ng-controller="My.Controller">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="site in sites">
            {{site.NodeName}} - {{site.NodeId}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have a controller as well, looks like this:

```
angular.module("umbraco").controller("My.Controller", function($scope) {
   ...
});
```

What I need is to put something instead of the trhee dots to grab the array from the json file.

I can get it working if I my controller looks like this (containing the array the controller file):

```
angular.module("umbraco").controller("My.Controller", function($scope) {
    $scope.sites = [
    {
        NodeName: "Planes",
        NodeId: "a93064"
    },
    {
        NodeName: "Bicycles",
        NodeId: "a49856"
    },
    {
        NodeName: "Cars",
        NodeId: "a19631"
    }
    ];
});
```

But I can't get it working if I'm trying to grab the array from the file on the server. I've tried a couple of different things including something like the $hhtp.get() etc. copied from around the web, but nothing seems to work :(

I hope that someone can help me out.

Thank you very much in advance.

/Kim

Comment: Could you post the response headers of your web service output? It's possible you've missed out some CORS headers to allow JavaScript to make a request. `$http` certainly seems to be one way to do it in this case, so possibly it's a CORS issue.. Do you see any errors in the JS console if you use a simple `$http.get()` call?

Comment: Ohh, sorry cgwyllie, didn't even see your comment before I saw the correct answer below. But thanks for yout time anyways.

Comment: No problem, glad you got it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your backend's JSON response is not well formatted. **NodeId** values have to be string, as they contain non-numeric characters.

```
[{
    "NodeId": "a93064",
    "NodeName": "Planes"
}, {
    "NodeId": "a49856",
    "NodeName": "Bicycles"
}, {
    "NodeId": "a19631",
    "NodeName": "Cars"
}]
```

After fixing that, you just need to use **$http** get method to make backend request.

```
.controller('My.Controller', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('returnsites.ashx').success(function(sites) {
      $scope.sites = sites;
    });
});
```

Here is a working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HXwqGPxDZ8QFNGJh1hIz?p=preview).

Answer (score 1):

An $http.get() should do the trick. Try:

```
$scope.sites = [];

$http.get('/services/returnsites.ashx').success(function(data) {
    $scope.sites = data;
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Mike. Halib get's the correct answer as he aswered first. But thanks to you as well for your time.

Comment: np, he must have answered as I was typing :)